# TSQL populate table with future days (different date formats)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to populate a table with different date formats and working days flags, starting with 2017-01-01, for each day, until 2020-12-31.

Is there some stored procedure that does this? (I imagine is pretty standard operation). I found all kind of "solutions", but most seem more like hacks than "standard operations".

Here's a sample from table I need to populate:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/647950/create-and-populate-date-dimension-for-data-wareho) article will especially help those people who work in Data warehouse and Business Intelligence. Whenever as a starting point, they need to set New Data warehouse, during this time they need to create and fill their Date Dimension with various values of Date, Date Keys, Day Type, Day Name Of Week, Month, Month Name, Quarter, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe theres something standard, already done within SQL server like what you want.

You could create a procedure and use 'dateadd' function within a loop to create all the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

This may get you started.  Not 100% clear on Relative{months/weeks/...}

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2017-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2020-12-31'

;with cte0(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
     ,cteD(D) As (Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@Date1,@Date2)+1) cast(DateAdd(DD,Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1,@Date1) as date) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4, cte0 N5, cte0 N6) -- 1 Million
 Select DateSK    = cast(Format(D,'yyyyMMdd') as int)
       ,FullDate  = cast(D as datetime)
       ,Day       = DatePart(DD,D)
       ,DayName   = DateName(DW,D)+', '+Format(D,'MMMM dd yyyy')
       ,DaySuffix = DateName(D,D)+case when DatePart(d, D) in (1,21,31) then 'st'
                                       when DatePart(d, D) in (2,22)    then 'nd'
                                       when DatePart(d, D) in (3,23)    then 'rd'
                                       else 'th' end
      ,DayOfWeek         = DateName(DW,D)
      ,DayOfWeekNumber   = DatePart(DW,D)
      ,DayOfWeekInMonth  = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By Year(D),Month(D),DatePart(DW,D) Order by D)
      ,DayOfYear         = DatePart(DAYOFYEAR,D)
      ,RelativeDays      = Row_Number() over (Order by D)
      ,WeekofYearNumber  = DatePart(WEEK,D)
      ,WeekofMonthNumber = Dense_Rank() over (Partition By Year(D),Month(D) Order by DatePart(WEEK,D))
      ,RelativeWeeks     = Dense_Rank() over (Order by Year(D),Month(D),DatePart(WEEK,D))
      ,CalendarMonthNumber = DatePart(MONTH,D)
      ,CalendarMonthName = DateName(MONTH,D)
      ,CalendarMonthShortName = Lower(Left(DateName(MONTH,D),3))
      ,RelativeMonths    = Dense_Rank() over (Order by Year(D),Month(D))
 From  cteD
 Order By D
```

Returns

[image]